# Text search in aggregation using pymongo

Tags: mongodb-query, pymongo, text-search

I have a collection named **users**, it has following attributes

```
{
“_id”: “937a04d3f516443e87abe8308a1fe83e”,
“username”: “andy”,
“full_name”: “andy white”,
“image” : “https://example.com/xyz.jpg”,
… etc
}
```

i want to make a text search on full_name and username using aggregation pipeline, so that if a user search for any 3 letters, then the most relevant full_name or username returned sorted by relevancy,
i have already created text index on username and full_name and then i tried query from below link:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/text-search-in-aggregation/#return-results-sorted-by-text-search-score

```
pipeline_stage = [
{"$match": {"$text": {"$search": “whit”}}},
{"$sort": {“score”: {"$meta": “textScore”}}},
{"$project": {“username”: 1,“full_name”: 1,“image”:1}}
]

stages = [*pipeline_stage]
users = users_db.aggregate(stages)
```

but i am getting below error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: FieldPath field names may not start with ‘$’. Consider using $getField or $setField., full error: {‘ok’: 0.0, ‘errmsg’: “FieldPath field names may not start with ‘$’. Consider using $getField or $setField.”, ‘code’: 16410, ‘codeName’: ‘Location16410’, ‘$clusterTime’: {‘clusterTime’: Timestamp(1657811022, 14), ‘signature’: {‘hash’: b’a\xb4rem\x02\xc3\xa2P\x93E\nS\x1e\xa6\xaa\xb0\xb1\x85\xb5’, ‘keyId’: 7062773414158663703}}, ‘operationTime’: Timestamp(1657811022, 14)}
```

I also tried below link (my query also below) but i am getting full text search results, not working for partial text search:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/text-search-in-aggregation/#match-on-text-score

```
pipeline_stage = [
    {"$match": {"$text": {"$search": search_key}}},
    {"$project": {"full_name": 1, "score": {"$meta": "textScore"}}},
]
```

Any help will be appreciated,

Note: I want to do partial text search, sorted by relevant records at top,

Thanks

Comment: This issue get resolved if i remove $project from the query, but with $project i am unable to run the query, with the error i mentioned above

Comment: `"$search"` is ["A string of terms"](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-text/).  I don't think you can use it to do a "partial text search".  Perhaps a regex could be used.

Comment: you are right @rickhg12hs, i am unable to do partial text search using $search in pipeline, do you have any other way to do a partial search and sort the relevant results on top in response

Comment: I would explore regexes and/or a [`"$function"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) that calculates some sort of "relevancy" or similarity (levenshtein distance?).

Answer (score 0):

Your project stage is incorrect, it should be

```
pipeline_stage = [
    {"$match": {"$text": {"$search": "and"}}},
    {"$sort": {"score": {"$meta": "textScore"}}},
    {"$project": { "username": "$username", "full_name": "$full_name", "image": "$image"}}
]
```

Also note if you use an English text search, words like `and` are not indexed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but after writing project stage i am still getting the same error i.e:

pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'. Consider using $getField or $setField., full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': "FieldPath field names may not start with '$'. Consider using $getField or $setField.", 'code': 16410, 'codeName': 'Location16410'...

Comment: and here "and" means initials of any name like andrew, andy to be searched, not conjunction literally

Comment: re point 1 what version of mongodb any pymongo are you running. Re point 2 `and` is on the stop list of english words c.f. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/fts/stop_words_english.txt

Comment: i am using MongoDB 5.0.9 Enterprise, Python 3.9.7 and pymongo 4.1.1, and i understand about the `and`, so leave it, its not my concern, my concern is partial search with relevant words on top, thats it

Comment: Have you tried replacing `and` with `andy`?

Comment: its a variable search search term, here `andy` is full word, which gives the search results, leave `andy` word for now due to confusion, Lets for example, i want to search `peterson` and if i write the complete search word like `peterson`, then i get the results, but if i write `peter`, search is failed as partial search is not working in this case

Comment: That's not how full-text search works in MongoDB. It only matches the full word. To search on a partial string use `$regex`.

Comment: i know how to use $regex for partial match, but $regex with this kind of search, where we need to sort the results based on most relevant records is still a question for me, and i dont know how to do a partial match and sort the relevant results on top

Comment: Maybe someone else has a better answer, but as far as I know you can't do that natively. It's either full-text, regex, or roll your own somehow.